# Layout within TabHost and TabWidget

Tags: android

I'm extremely new to Android and just trying to get my head around these layouts.

I've got several tabs which contain a LinearLayout with a TabWidget and FrameLayout as children. In the FrameLayout I'd like a certain percentage at the bottom of the screen to be reserved for a table, the rest above to be filled with an image.

How can I replicate this in the Android XML?

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the `FrameLayout`, put a `LinearLayout`. In the `LinearLayout`, have your "table" (`TableLayout`?) and image (`ImageView`?). Set the table's and image's `android:layout_height="0px"` and `android:layout_weight` to be whatever percentage you want for each.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I'd misunderstood the layout_weight to be some kind of priority of size - ie this widget is more important than that one - rather than an actual proportion.